# UseEffect bucle infinito al obtener data de Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-auth

Tengo un problema con un componente que estoy haciendo, en el que necesito obtener data de Firestore para actualizar algunos campos.

tengo primero un useEffect que obtiene la info de firestore y la guarda con el setData

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(docRef) {
            const getDoc = () => {
                docRef && db.collection("prospects").doc(docRef).onSnapshot(function(doc) {
                    let tempPassword = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
                    setData({...data, ...doc.data(), password: tempPassword})
                })}
                return getDoc();
            }
    }, [docRef])
```

una vez que el usuario termina el proceso se va a crear un usuario con firebase auth y se va a guardar en una coleccion llamada users, pero antes necesito comprobar si ese usuario no ha realizado antes otro registro, en caso de que así sea, obtener de ese registro el uid para sobreescribir el documento y el tempPassword para enviarselo al usuario. 
Para eso escribí este código en el que uso el correo que ingresó el usuario y que ya está guardado en data por el useEffect anterior, para buscar en la coleccion users:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!data) return
            db.collection("users").where("email", "==", data.email)
            .get()
            .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                    setData({...data, uid: doc.data().uid, password: doc.data().password})
                });
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
            });
    }, [data])
```

pero esto me está generando un bucle infinito, que si bien funciona, me está provocando algunos errores con otras validaciones y que esté funcionando muy lento.

Espero no haber hecho la explicación muy confusa, y de antemano agradezco si alguien me pudiera ayudar.

Saludos

Comment: la explicación es confusa, no se entiende lo que intentas hacer. Por que no usas el uid como id de tus documentos en la collection users? en vez de `collection("users").where("email", "==", data.email)` podrías hacer `collection("users").doc(uid)`

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem tengo varias vistas, y en cada una se llenan distintos forms, en uno de ellos el usuario ingresa su email, todos esos forms se guardan en una coleccion llamada prospects, pero en este ultimo form si el usuario termina el proceso, se crea un usuario en auth con el email que previamente ingresó, y todos esos datos que fue guardando en prospects se guardan en otra coleccion llamada users, en la cual el documento se crea con el uid de auth, en caso de que el usuario exista tendría que sobreescribir solamente los datos existentes, por eso trato de obtener el documento por email

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas pasando data como dependencia de useEffect y cuando obtenés el valor de firebase actualizas el estado data obligando al useEffect a ejecutarse de nuevo, para evitar eso tenés que pasar una array vacío en las dependencias, así:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(!data) return
            db.collection("users").where("email", "==", data.email)
            .get()
            .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                    setData({...data, uid: doc.data().uid, password: doc.data().password})
                });
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
            });
    }, [])
```

Con esto le decís a useEffect que se ejecute solamente una vez.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, lo intenté de ese modo, pero el useEffect se ejecuta antes de que el primer useEffect obtenga data, y me da error porque no encuentra el data.email

Comment: Bueno, podrías mostrar más de tu código para ver qué se ejecuta antes y cuando se ejecuta